# Does react native fast refresh support module.hot.dispose data argument?

Tags: javascript, react-native, storybook

I'm working on the react-native storybook project and I'm trying to re-use some code that is used to load files (stories) into the application. On the web version of the app this code is used to keep track of the previous list of story files (previousexports) so that when you reload it doesn't duplicate the stories.

```
if (m && m.hot && m.hot.dispose) {
  ({ previousExports = new Map() } = m.hot.data || {});
  m.hot.dispose((data) => {
    loaded = false;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    data.previousExports = previousExports;
  });
  m.hot.accept();
}
```

Link to this code: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/f2cc478dcf1e249c29a1014f7d53d71931f824f8/lib/core-client/src/preview/loadCsf.ts#L237

However when I run this code on react native the data field is undefined. In the webpack implementation of hot module reloading the dispose function has this signature.

```
__WebpackModuleApi.Hot.dispose(callback: (data: any) => void): void
```

With this description

> Add a one time handler, which is executed when the current module
> code is replaced. Here you should destroy/remove any persistent
> resource you have claimed/created. If you want to transfer state to
> the new module, add it to data object. The data will be available at
> module.hot.data on the new module.

I'm struggling to find the react native api for hot module replacement. As far as I know the fast refresh implementation still uses a similar api and these m.hot calls are triggered on fast  refresh calls.

Does react native just not support this data parameter and where can I find information about the module.hot api for react-native/metro?

What I've found so far are the following:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16604#issuecomment-528663101

https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/09/18/version-0.61#fast-refresh

https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading

With notable information being

> Fast Refresh relies on several pieces working together:
>
> - "Hot module replacement" mechanism in the module system.
>
>   - That is usually also provided by the bundler.
>   - E.g. in webpack, `module.hot` API lets you do this.

> HMR in React Native extends the module system by introducing the hot object. This API is based on Webpack's one. The hot object exposes a function called accept which allows you to define a callback that will be executed when the module needs to be hot swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a discussion with a colleague since asking this question here which lead me to believe that the data param is not supported.

Also looking into the metro code (metro bundler for react native) appears to confirm this.

If you look at the require polyfill in the metro repository you can see the following type definitions.

```
type HotModuleReloadingCallback = () => void;
type HotModuleReloadingData = {|
  _acceptCallback: ?HotModuleReloadingCallback,
  _disposeCallback: ?HotModuleReloadingCallback,
  _didAccept: boolean,
  accept: (callback?: HotModuleReloadingCallback) => void,
  dispose: (callback?: HotModuleReloadingCallback) => void,
|};
```

As you can see the dispose function shares the same callback signature `()=>void`.

you can find the source for the code above [here](https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/4fea2bd5a72c7c3e3030adc07a0dd97322e63c5a/packages/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js#L30)

I ended up going with a different solution where I store the exports in a global variable. It's not ideal but it's working. That global variable looks a bit like this `global.previousExports = new Map<any, string>();` and I extended the node global type to avoid type errors.